# Why doesn't ChangeListener's getSource() return a pre-cast object of the type used to generate an event?

Tags: java, swing, changelistener

Instead of having to cast the ChangeEvent Object back into a JSpinner Object so that I can access the getValue() method, why doesn't e.getSource() simply return a pre-cast object of the type used to generate the event?  The first usage of e.getSource() makes it clear that it KNOWS a JSpinner is being used, so why not just cast it back?  It seems like it'd be simpler.  I'm assuming there are safety reasons not to do this, but I'd like to see or hear of a concrete example why that would be a bad thing to have as the default usage.

Is it unsafe?  Is it just bad architecture?

```
public class SpinnerPanel extends JPanel implements ChangeListener {

...

SpinnerPanel()
{
    birthdaySpinner.addChangeListener(this);
    add(birthdaySpinner);
}

@Override
public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) 
{
    System.out.println(e.getSource());

    JSpinner spinner = (JSpinner)e.getSource();
    System.out.println(spinner.getValue());
}
}
```

Comment: Because the ChangeListener can be used by multiple different components all with there own requirements for the source object.  When the API was designed, generics didn't exist and changing the API could effect production code currently running

Comment: Ah, okay.  I don't think I've written much code where a Listener is attached to multiple things, but your comment reminded me it could be done, which explains the reasoning concisely.  Feel a little dumb to have asked, but at least that little tidbit is filed away in my head now.

Comment: Any chance you have a specific code snippet to elaborate the point?  I'm still thinking about it and having a bit of a hard time visualizing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fact that the source will be a `JSpinner` is known *at runtime*. The kind of “automatic type casts” you describe are possible with generics at *compile time*, but at that time there is no telling where the listener might end up. For example, you could take your spinner, obtain a list of all listeners, and then add these listeners to another widget like a check box. There is nothing in your code to tell the compiler at compile time that this won't happen, so there is nothing to tell the compiler that the source will always be a spinner.

It would *theoretically* be possible to use generics in some way. You could have a `ChangeEvent<T>` for changes originating from a component of class `T`. You could have a `ChangeListener<T>` with a method `stateChanged(ChangeEvent<? extends T>)`. But then what would be the type for all listeners of a given component of class `T`? If it were `List<ChangeEvent<T>>` then you wouldn't be allowed to add a generic `ChangeListener<Object>` to that list. So it would have to be `List<ChangeEvent<? super T>>`. But if you had such a list in any component, then it would be the same type for all derived components, instead of a more specific type like the generics approach would suggest.

So on the whole I think this generics approach would make the code a lot harder to write and maintain, would likely leave loopholes in some places, would probably be horrible in terms of backwards compatibility, and on the whole would not be worth the effort.